# Почему non-static блок выполняется до вызова конструктора?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Изучая тесты по java, заметил некое несоответствие. В первом вопросе, "указать результат вывода":

```
public class QTest { 
    { 
        System.out.print("1"); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.print("2"); 
        new QTest(); 
    } 

    static { 
        System.out.print("3"); 
    } 
}
```

правильный ответ: "321", то есть после static блока следует вызов конструктора и, наконец, вызов non-staic блока.

Во втором вопросе аналогичного плана:

```
public class Test {     
    { 
        System.out.println("1"); 
    } 

    Test () { 
        System.out.println("2"); 
    } 

    static { 
        System.out.println("3"); 
    } 

    { 
        System.out.println("4"); 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        new Test(); 
    } 
}
```

правильным ответом будет "3142", то есть вызов non-static блоков предшествует вызову конструктора. С чем может быть связана эта разница?

Благодарю.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Статический блок инициализации** вызывается при первом обращении к классу, вне зависимости от того, созали вы его экземпляр, или вызвали статический метод. Т.е. по сути сразу после того, как класс был загружен в оперативную память **classLoader**'ом. Поэтому он никак не связан с экземплярами класса, и тем более с обычными блоками инициализации.

**Блок инициализации** вызывается при создания **экземпляра объекта**, **после** вызова родительских конструкторов и **до** вызова конструктора данного класса. Т.е. вызов `super` в конструкторе данного класса будет выполнен **до** вызова блоков инициализации, а весь остальной конструктор - **после**. Если в конструкторе данного класса нет вызова `super`, он все равно происходит (неявно). По сути у блока инициализации такой же приоритет, как и у поля. И они инициализируются по-очереди.

**Конструктор** вызывается тогда, когда все поля объекта определены (в java любое поле объекта будет определено при создании экземпляра своим значением по-умолчанию, даже если это не сделано явно).

И да. В первом примере у вас **2** выводится не в **конструкторе**, а в **методе** `main`. И при вызове конструктора из метода `main` сначала инициализируются поля нового объекта и вызываются блоки инициализации, потом вызывается сам конструктор, и после этого продолжает выполняться код метода `main` с уже созданным экземпляром.

Как-то так. Прочитайте в интернете про **initializer block**, **static initializer block**.

Comment: Большое спасибо. То если бы в первом примере `2` выводилась бы не в рамках метода `main()`, а в рамках конструктора `QTest()` мы бы получили на вывод: `312`, верно?

Comment: Да, верно, добавил в ответ

Comment: Да, с данным вопросом полностью разобрался. Благодарю.

Comment: Немножко поправлю. Блок инициализации вызывается не совсем до конструктора. Каждый дефолтный конструктор содержит неявный вызов `super()`, так вот блок инициализации вызывается после вызова этого `super()`.

Comment: Да, забыл про наследование, обобщил и поправил ответ

Comment: Полностью согласен, да. Благодарю.